# Solr delta-import not working

Tags: solr, config, dataimporthandler

Full import and deletedPkQuery works ,
I've traced the database server both the deltaQuery and deletedPkQuery are executed.

ive executed these queries manually many times and they do indeed return row(s), but

It does not fetch any rows. Last thing i did was to output the FILE_ID as id on all the queries. Still doesnt work.

```
<dataConfig>

<dataSource name="db" type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=norway_operations;responseBuffering=adaptive;selectMethod=cursor" user="noropuser" password="noropuser" autoCommit="false" transactionIsolation="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED"holdability="CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT"/>
<dataSource name="bin" type="BinFileDataSource"  basePath="D:\OPG_FILESTORE"/>

<document>

    <entity name="file" dataSource="db" pk="id" query="select FILE_ID as id, CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY_NAME, FILENAME, FILE_MIME_TYPE, PATH, LAST_MODIFIED as last_modified from DOCUMENTS"
            deltaQuery="select FILE_ID as id from DOCUMENTS where LAST_MODIFIED > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'" 
            deltaImportQuery="select FILE_ID as id, CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY_NAME, FILENAME, FILE_MIME_TYPE, PATH, LAST_MODIFIED as last_modified from DOCUMENTS where FILE_ID = '${dih.delta.id}'" 
            deletedPkQuery="delete from PK_DELETE_HISTORY output DELETED.PK AS id where PK_NAME = 'FILE_ID'" >

        <field column="id" name="id" />
        <field column="CATEGORY_ID" name="categoryId" />
        <field column="CATEGORY_NAME" name="category" />
        <field column="FILENAME" name="filename" />
        <field column="FILE_MIME_TYPE" name="content_type" />
        <field column="last_modified" name="last_modified" />

        <entity name="tika" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" url="${file.PATH}" parser="org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser" format="text" dataSource="bin" onError="continue">                
            <field column="text" name="content" />
            <field column="title" name="title"/>
            <field column="subject" name="subject"/>
            <field column="description" name="description"/>
            <field column="comments" name="comments"/>
            <field column="author" name="author"/>
            <field column="keywords" name="keywords"/>
            <field column="url"  name="url"/>
            <field column="content_type" name="content_type" />                
            <field column="links"  name="links" />                
        </entity>            
    </entity>        
</document>
```

Trace

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=180150003
declare @p5 int
set @p5=-1
exec sp_cursoropen @p1 output,N'select FILE_ID as id from DOCUMENTS where LAST_MODIFIED > ''2014-02-06 15:02:40''',16,8193,@p5 output
select @p1, @p5
```

When i run this manually it returns 1 row

Response:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <response>
- <lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int> 
  <int name="QTime">31</int> 
  </lst>
- <lst name="initArgs">
- <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str> 
  <int name="rows">0</int> 
  <int name="start">0</int> 
  </lst>
  </lst>
  <str name="command">delta-import</str> 
  <str name="mode">debug</str> 
  <arr name="documents" /> 
  <lst name="verbose-output" /> 
  <str name="status">idle</str> 
  <str name="importResponse" /> 
- <lst name="statusMessages">
  <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">2</str> 
  <str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str> 
  <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str> 
  <str name="Delta Dump started">2014-02-06 15:32:20</str> 
  <str name="Identifying Delta">2014-02-06 15:32:20</str> 
  <str name="Deltas Obtained">2014-02-06 15:32:20</str> 
  <str name="Building documents">2014-02-06 15:32:20</str> 
  <str name="Total Changed Documents">0</str> 
  <str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str> 
  <str name="Time taken">0:0:0.16</str> 
  </lst>
  <str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.</str> 
  </response>
```

Comment: Are you saying deltaImport doesn't work, but full  import works?

Comment: Oops,it's delta-import.. I missed the subject :-)

Comment: Full imports works, but delta doesn't

Answer (score 4):

Things might worth looking for:

**1.Timestamp saved in `dataimport.properties` config file**

This happens to me before

Running delta-import (successfully) will update the {dataimporter.last_index_time} in conf/dataimport.properties file. And next time, your query may run based on the new timestamp, which may return zero rows unless you updated the database.

**2. dataimporter.delta.id and dataimporter.last_index_time**

**dataimporter.delta.id** should be **dih.delta.id**

**last_index_time** remains in the  **dataimporter** namespace. `**dataimporter.last_index_time** works at least in solr 4.2.0. dih.last_index_time might works too as it was mentioned in the solr wiki, but I haven't test it`

**3. Timestamp need to be converted to proper DataTime datatype depends on the DB .**

In case of SQL server:

```
LAST_MODIFIED_DATETIME > convert(datetime,'${dataimporter.last_index_time}')
```

Comment: no, i check it and it doesn't change. also i trace the sql server and then run the query manually and it returns rows

Comment: How about just change dih.delta.id? The last_index_time no need to change.

Comment: tried query="select FILE_ID as id, CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY_NAME, FILENAME, FILE_MIME_TYPE, PATH, LAST_MODIFIED from DOCUMENTS where '${dih.request.clean}' != 'false' or LAST_MODIFIED > '${dih.last_index_time}'", that does not do anything either. So if clean=false it returns documents based on dih.last_index_time.

Comment: I should be more specific in my earlier response: please try ro remove the file `dataimport.properties`, and use ${dataimporter.last_index_time} and ${dih.delta.id}

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select FILE_ID as id from DOCUMENTS where LAST_MODIFIED > 'Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970' Processing Document # 1

Comment: I see the time is 1 hour behind

Comment: :-) Now the issue might be on the query **select FILE_ID as id from DOCUMENTS where LAST_MODIFIED > 'Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970'**. Perhaps the time 'Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970' need to be converted to the DataTime type if you are using SQL server

Comment: i removed "where LAST_MODIFIED > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'" from deltaQuery and it imports everything

Comment: Cool! this might confirm that the problem is on the datatime conversion.  Please try **"where LAST_MODIFIED > convert(datetime,'${dataimporter.last_index_time}')"**

Comment: that doesn't do anything, did cast(... as datetime), and also i put pack the .properties file.  Maybe i have to escape the > with &gt;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46948/discussion-between-leoh-and-oddi)

Comment: this query works on the server: select FILE_ID as id from DOCUMENTS where LAST_MODIFIED > CONVERT(datetime, '2014-02-06 16:09:41') and returns rows, but solr does not do anything. if i replace > with != delta-import imports everything. also i change all the last modified timestamps to current so that it should pick up everything

Comment: i also create a stored procedure exec dih_delta_file '${dataimporter.last_index_time}', and its exactly the same problem. if i change the procedure and remove the where clause it starts processing everything

Comment: How the Last_modified column defined in the database? Is it varchar or datatime?

Comment: datetime, i also created another core with different data, same problem. but if i omit the where clause it imports everything

Comment: select BASE_ID from vKNOWLEDGE_BASE where '${dataimporter.last_index_time}' &lt; TIMESTAMP does not work

select BASE_ID from vKNOWLEDGE_BASE where '1970-01-01 00:00:00' &lt; TIMESTAMP works

It does not fetch any rows from the database, but when run query manually it returns row(s)

Comment: "select BASE_ID from vKNOWLEDGE_BASE where '2013-02-07 13:04:43' < TIMESTAMP" returns 10 rows when run manually.

the response from solr "Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 6 documents. Deleted 0 documents."

Comment: Right, the problem is where the query executed with the time string read from the dataimport.properties. If you tune the log level that able to show the actual SQL for the original delta query, chances are it tell the exact problem :if it's a bug in solr or in configuration.

Comment: if i change the where clause to where BASE_ID in (,,,) and put in the ids of the rows returned by the query with the timestamp manually it works. But it does not work even if i replace '${dataimporter.last_index_time}' with '' the last_index_time.

Comment: if i replace '${dataimporter.last_index_time}' with '2014-02-07 13:44:27' i get the same result, but if i set the year back 1 year to '2013-02-07 13:44:27' it does indeed process documents. and when the originial deltaquery "select BASE_ID from vKNOWLEDGE_BASE where '2014-02-07 13:44:27' < TIMESTAMP" manually it returns 2 documents. i can take these ids and modify the where clause in the data-config.xml to where BASE_ID in (2555, 2556) and i will process these documents

Comment: yes. Note that every delta update will update the timestamp in dataimport.properties file

Comment: It's the date format, if i change the dataimport.properties file date format from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS it works. Just don't know why. Its running in tomcat on windows. -Duser.locale=en -Duser.region=US set the regional settings to english in windows. SQL Server language is english and uses the correct date format. So this is something internally in SOLR.

Comment: If possible, you can configure the "<propertyWriter dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" type="SimplePropertiesWriter" directory="data" filename="my_dih.properties" locale="en_US" />" for desired date format.

Comment: Also if you think elyograg and I helped in finding the problem, please feel free to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

There are some bugs in certain versions with last_index_time.  You haven't indicated which Solr version you're on, but most people these days are on 4.x.

Also, there are some bugs where the old dataimporter property namespace doesn't work.  With 4.x you should be using the dih property namespace, which means dih.last_index_time and dih.delta.id instead of dataimporter.* for the property names.

Comment: I'm using Apache Solr 4.6.1, i thought that "dih" was the old namespace.. i'll try to switch to dih tomorrow...

Comment: OK.  You probably need to obtain logs of the actual SQL that DIH is sending.

If you go to the logging tab in the admin UI and you're using one of the supported logging frameworks, you can change the level of the org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource class to DEBUG (or FINE, depending on your framework).  Then you need to perform the import and find the logfile for Solr on disk.

Once you know whether the SQL is correct, we will know which direction to look next.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and figured out that deltaImportQuery is case sensitive

Made my id Column as "ID"

deltaImportQuery="select id,state,name,place,city from temp where **ID='${dih.delta.ID}**

Comment: You should use the same case you used in the column attribute of your field. 
Solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running SOLR in Tomcat 7 on windows. Tracing the ODBC connection i see that the language is set to Norwegian. (Norwegian = Norsk) in Norwegian ;)

```
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language Norsk
set dateformat dmy
set datefirst 1
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

JVM is started with these args

```
-Duser.region=US
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Oslo
```

It didn't make any difference whether is was set Norwegian or English

Adding a propertyWriter tag to the configuration file fixed the problem.

```
<dataConfig>
<propertyWriter dateFormat="yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss" type="SimplePropertiesWriter" directory="D:/tmp" filename="knowledgebase.dih.properties" locale="English (United States)" />
<dataSource name="db" type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=norway_operations;responseBuffering=adaptive;selectMethod=cursor" user="noropuser" password="noropuser" autoCommit="false" transactionIsolation="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED" holdability="CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT" />

<document>

    <entity type="a" name="knowledge" dataSource="db" pk="BASE_ID" query="select * from vKNOWLEDGE_BASE"
            deltaQuery="select BASE_ID from vKNOWLEDGE_BASE where '${dataimporter.last_index_time}' &lt; TIMESTAMP" 
            deltaImportQuery="select * from vKNOWLEDGE_BASE where BASE_ID = '${dataimporter.delta.BASE_ID}'" 
            deletedPkQuery="delete from PK_DELETE_HISTORY output DELETED.PK AS BASE_ID where PK_NAME = 'BASE_ID'" >

        <field column="BASE_ID" name="id" />
        <field column="CATEGORY_ID" name="categoryId" />
        <field column="CATEGORY_NAME" name="category" />
        <field column="DESCRIPTION" name="description" />
        <field column="SOLUTION" name="solution" />
        <field column="USER_FULL_NAME" name="author" />
        <field column="SOFTWARE_VERSION" name="software_version" />
        <field column="TIMESTAMP" name="last_modified" />

        <entity name="keywords" dataSource="db" pk="KEYWORD_ID" query="select KNOWLEDGE_KEYWORDS.* from KNOWLEDGE_KEYWORDS_TO_BASE left join KNOWLEDGE_KEYWORDS on (KNOWLEDGE_KEYWORDS_TO_BASE.KEYWORD_ID = KNOWLEDGE_KEYWORDS.KEYWORD_ID) where  KNOWLEDGE_KEYWORDS_TO_BASE.BASE_ID = '${knowledge.BASE_ID}'">                
            <field column="KEYWORD_NAME" name="keywords" />              
        </entity>      
    </entity>        
</document>
```

It's also possible to add a language option to the JdbcDataSource url.

`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=XXX;responseBuffering=adaptive;selectMethod=cursor;language=XXX`

I did not test this, but i assume this would also fix the problem if it had been set to english, because in the SQL server query the language is set to Norwegian, but the date format used in the where clause to compare the LAST_MODIFIED column was yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and the default format for Norwegian is yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.

Answer (score 0):

Solr seems to save timestamps in `dataimport.properties` in `UTC` timezone, so you need to convert you timezone in database to `UTC` before compare to values in `dataimport.properties`.

e.g

```
-- for mysql, following would convert `update_date` to utc before compare in where clause
deltaQuery="select id from book where status = 0 and CONVERT_TZ(`update_date`, @@session.time_zone, '+00:00') &gt; '${dih.last_index_time}';"
```